# What is the most commonly used transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, jfet

Just a question about transistors from a rookie.
I was wondering what kind of transistor is most commonly used? Bipolar transistors? JFET? MOSFET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest volume of discrete transistors used in products are bipoler transistors. This is mainly due to their low cost. Most of the transistors in the world are however MOSFETs inside integrated circuits (chips). A single digital IC often contains millions of transistors.